# Covariance matrix of two i.i.d. Gaussian random variables

Tags: matrices, random-variables, independence, covariance, variance

I have two i.i.d. Gaussian random variables:

$$Z_a -  \mathcal N(0,N_a)$$
$$Z_b -  \mathcal N(0,N_b)$$

I am trying to construct the covariance matrix of $(Z_a,Z_b)$.

I guess it should be something like: $$(0,\begin{bmatrix}
        N_aN_b & pN_aN_b \\
        pN_aN_b & N_aN_b \\
        \end{bmatrix})$$

But it appears that it is not.

Comment: i.i.d means independent and identically distributed.  Identical means $N_a$ = $N_b$.  Independent means $\text{Cov}(Z_a, Z_b) = 0$.  Combine both, you get $$\left(\begin{matrix}Z_a\\Z_b\end{matrix}\right)\sim \left(0, \left[\begin{matrix}N_a & 0 \\ 0 & N_a\end{matrix}\right]\right)$$

Comment: @Guangliang Thank you! What would be then if I add:

$$Y_a=X+Z_a$$

where $X \sim (0,σ^2)$ 

Is $Y_a$ going to be:

$$Y_a \sim \left(0, \left[\begin{matrix}N_a+σ^2 & σ^2 \\ σ^2 & N_a+σ^2\end{matrix}\right]\right)$$

Comment: Is $X$ independent of $Z_a$?  If so, $Y_a\sim (0, N_a+\sigma^2)$.

Comment: @Guangliang In my situation they are independent. Thank you a lot. Just one last question what if they were not independent?

Comment: In general, $\text{Var}(X+Z) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Z) + \text{Cov}(X,Z)$